# How to apply a continuous gradient to a shape with text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, shapes, gradient

I'm trying to apply a left-to-right gradient to a simple image to an image such as the one below:

I've learned how to apply the gradient to text, but I don't know how to extend it to the bullseye illustration on the right. I've tried many permutations of things, such as grouping the items, expanding them, creating the type outline, using the gradient tool, etc., but none of them seem to work.

How do I do this?

[image: Image with text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Group** the type with the artwork (bullseye).

Then add a new fill via the **Appearance Panel** so it is **above** the `<Contents>` item....

[image]

Then use the Gradient Tool and Gradient Panel to adjust as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much Scott, in my case by applying the fill to the grouped object the bullseye is completely filling with color (including the middle band) - how do I build it so that it behaves like in your case? Is it with pathfinder operations?

Comment: @alexcs I would *guess* then that your bullseye is using a thick stroke for the outer ring. Select that stroke and choose `Object > Expand` from the menu to convert the stroked path to a *shape* with a fill. Then things should operate as in my example.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to group the object, but the gradient tool for some reason does not allow you to apply a gradient to a grouped object directly (as you can see me demonstrate in the middle of the attached GIF). I'm not sure if this is a bug or not - but there is a workaround!

Group the text and the object, then add a new fill from the appearance panel.
From here, you need to open the gradient panel and double-click the ramp. From there, you can use the gradient toolbar item to manipulate the fill, or you can continue modifying it from the gradient panel.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

There could be different ways to achieve this, but here's one way:

- Convert text to outlines via Type → Create Outlines. Keep an editable copy if you need to.
- Select all, including bullseye and apply gradient. This will apply a gradient to each individual letter and shape.
- Hit <kbd>G</kbd> and drag your mouse around around, see what happens.
- Take it from there and customize.